# What is a good 3D library with boolean operations for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, 3d

A good friend asked me for help regarding some 3D library for iOS but I was not able to find a proper solution:

Following is the text of the email I got from him:

We are trying to build an iOS app with 3D functionality. To do this, we need to port a 3D library with boolean operations into iOS. Our project is not open source so we need to use 3D libraries that protect the release of our code, namely ones with LGPL, Apache 2, BSD or MIT licenses. So far, we have only found one suitable 3D library with boolean operations - the GTS Library, a library in C for manipulating 3D triangular surface meshes. GTS - The GNU Triangulated Surface Library   The GTS Library, in turn, relies on the GLib library, core application building blocks for libraries and applications written in C. https://developer.gnome.org/glib/

The issue is that we have been trying to port the GLib library into iOS for weeks, but have not been successful.

**Here are our questions:**

- Do you have any suggestions on how we can port the GLib library into
  iOS without errors?
- If we can't port GLib into iOS, then do you have any suggestions for
  alternative 3D libraries with boolean operations (and an LGPL or
  equivalent license) that we can port to iOS instead of the GTS
  library?

Answer (score 0):

A good library would be [Ninevehgl](http://nineveh.gl/). Have a look at that.